# Liquibase Only Running Single Changelog

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I have a master changelog set up that contains all of my changelogs, which looks something like this:

```
{
   "databaseChangeLog": [
   {
      "include": [
          { "file": "changelog/4.0/insert-languages-4.0.0.json" },
          { "relativeToChangelogFile":"true"}
      ],
      "include": [
          { "file": "changelog/4.0/Create-order-datetime-concat4.0.1.json"},
          { "relativeToChangelogFile":"true"}
      ]
   }
]}
```

The problem is only the last changelog in the list actually runs. I would like all of them to run one after another instead of just the last one. I set "onFail" for all prerequisites to "CONTINUE" so even if it hits an error it should continue with the rest of the changelogs. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is incorrect: the element include has to be closed

```
{
  "databaseChangeLog": [
    {
      "include": [
        {
          "file": "include/include1.json"
        },
        {
          "relativeToChangelogFile": "true"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "include": [
        {
          "file": "include/include2.json"
        },
        {
          "relativeToChangelogFile": "true"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```